# threejs retrieving euler angles from trackball controls?

Tags: three.js

I am using the three.js trackball controls to rotate around my object.  However, when the user is not actively using the trackball, I want the view to slowly just rotate around the vertical axis.

Anyone know how I would do that?  I tried just changing camera.rotation.y but it didn't do anything.

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use `OrbitControls` instead, and set `controls.autoRotate = true`.